# OnGlobalLayoutListener: deprecation and compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, deprecated

I have to use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` object and then to remove the listener, I had a problem with deprecated methods that I resolve with following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LinearLayout llTotal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mmc_ll);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = llTotal.getViewTreeObserver();
    if(vto.isAlive()){
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //
                // mycode
                //
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16) {
                    removeLayoutListenerPre16(llTotal.getViewTreeObserver(),this);
                } else {
                    removeLayoutListenerPost16(llTotal.getViewTreeObserver(), this);
                }
            } 
        });
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void removeLayoutListenerPre16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
}

@TargetApi(16)
private void removeLayoutListenerPost16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```

Is it correct? There is a better way to handle compatibility?

Running the code in emulator with API 10 I have the following warning in LogCat

```
04-24 09:30:12.565: I/dalvikvm(471): Could not find method android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener, referenced from method com.my.project.ActivityHome.removeLayoutListenerPost16
04-24 09:30:12.565: W/dalvikvm(471): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2950: Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver;.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener (Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener;)V
```

Can I ignore them of I have to fix in some way?

Answer (score 146):

I'm using this in my project:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    } else {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```

looks similar to yours.
Tested on different devices (4.2.2 & 2.3.3) and it run perfectly.
seems like it's the only way....If you find anything else I would like to know it.
good luck

**2020 EDIT**
This approach is very very obsolete. I hope you moved your code to Kotlin.
Now we can use doOnPreDraw function when using ktx library.
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).doOnPreDraw(kotlin.Function1)

Comment: At the beginning I used your code but it give an error (Call requires API level 16 (current min is 8): android.view.ViewTreeObserver#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener) and a Warning (The method removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) from the type ViewTreeObserver is deprecated). My code resolve those issues but give the LogCat warning

Comment: warning is fine. it's because you're using jar of some sdk version with deprecated function for devices < sdk. so you can still use it.

Comment: @crbin1 you can add @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) before the function declaration , if you wish to avoid seeing this warning/error.

Comment: Google, this is horrible.

Answer (score 39):

I think the correct way is using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and `Build.VERSION_CODES`:

```
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
            } else {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
            }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to pass the listener to `removeGlobalLayoutListener` instead of `this`

Answer (score 10):

```
    mView.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            //
            // mycode
            //
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

Of course that check the Android version and call the correct method is much more prudent, but if you take a look on the Android source code you can see something interesting:

```
 @Deprecated
    public void removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
        removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim);
    }
```

This code was snipped from API 18

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html):

> This method was deprecated in API level 16. Use #removeOnGlobalLayoutListener instead

Works like a charm.