# Layout width return is zero in first call to onResume()

Tags: android

I have to set an image in my activity and in my scenario the image covers fairly large portion of the activity. However I want to keep its width/height to be no more than 33% of its parent viewGroup's width.

I am dynamically changing the ImageView's dimension at runtime using this code.

```
     @Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();       

    //try to resize the imageview according to current width of container layout
    int nWidthPix = findViewById(R.id.layout_info).getWidth();      
    ImageView imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_main);
    imView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    int imViewWidth = nWidthPix/3;
    imView.setMaxWidth(imViewWidth);
    imView.setMaxHeight(imViewWidth);
    //
    }
```

The problem is that nWidthPix which is width of RelativeLayout which contains my ImageView is returned 0 in the first call to onResume() that is when the app is launched for first time. As a result image is not shown , in the subsequent calls to onResume() it returns 720 which is correct.

I am guessing that since the view is not really shown yet before the first call on onResume it does not know the width ? but then we can find views on the other hand even before the activity is shown for the first time. .. Not sure what's causing it.

Help

Comment: What happens when you add setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUTNAME); after super.onResume(); ?

Comment: setContView is done in the onCreate which is called before onResume() not after onResume()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ViewTreeObserver` of the root layout and set an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to know when the layout finishes loading. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189525/ongloballayoutlistener-deprecation-and-compatibility) answer for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

View always report 0 as their width and height before they've been *measured* by the framework. `onResume()` is too soon to query this information, unfortunately.

If the parent view is the Activity itself, then you can get the window's dimensions (for example with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)) and use those values. Otherwise you need to postpone execution of this code until the layout pass is complete (via an [`OnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)).