# Get height and width of a textview set using layout weights?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have set TextViews in a linear layout using layout weights.

```
   linearLayout.setWeightSum(7f);

   for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
     TextView tv= new TextView(this);
     tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f));
     tv.setText("sometext");
     linearLayout.addView(tv);
   }
```

How do I get the width and height of these TextViews after the layout is drawn?

tv.getWidth() and tv.getHeight() return 0;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Comment: If anyone else comes across this problem and is after a quicker way to do this, there are several options on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/4601149)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

> getViewTreeObserver

as

```
 yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Ensure you call it only once :
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            // get size of view here
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was most helpful. Thanks! Wish there was a shorter way though.

Comment: Yeah, Once I lingered this problem for almost 5-6 hours ,then got this solution

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190337/2437655 for removeGlobalOnLayoutListener deprecation

Answer (score -1):

Try Following

```
TextView mLblDesc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mLblDesc);
        mLblDesc.getMaxHeight();
        mLblDesc.getMaxWidth();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns height as -1 and weight as 2147483647.