# Translate animation for recyclerview and textview not smooth

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, translate-animation

I want to show a `TextView`below the `Toolbar`, which should appear in case there is a new event coming in. It should slide down from below the `Toolbar`, appear for 1-2secs and then slide up again. Below the `TextView` is a `RecyclerView` with several items ordered in a `GridLayout`.

[image: layout with textview and recyclerview]

To achieve this, I'm using a `TranslateAnimation` to let the animation slide up again:

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -tvStatus.getHeight());
animate.setDuration(1000);
animate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        tvStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
tvStatus.startAnimation(animate);
```

The sliding animation of the `TextView` itself is working fine, but the `RecyclerView` doesn't animate so well. The `TextView` slides up again until it is hidden and there is a gap for a short time.
[image: gap after textview disappears]

And then the `ReclerView`just jumps up, which doesn't look very nice.

**My question is:** How can I adjust my code to make the `RecylerView`slide up as well when the `TextView`starts to slide up?

**EDIT - Solution:**

I adjusted my solution including the input from [Francescs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135887/4779830). I solved the animation without a translation, just by changing the height of the view.

**Method to expand statusbar:**

```
public void expand() {
                    //set Visible
                    tvStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mHeight);
                    mAnimator.setDuration(600);
                    mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    mAnimator.start();
}
```

**Method to collapse statusbar:**

```
private void collapse() {


        int finalHeight = tvStatus.getHeight();
                    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);
                    mAnimator.setDuration(500);
                    mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    mAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            tvStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                    mAnimator.start();
}
```

**Value Animator:**

```
private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                //Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = tvStatus.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                tvStatus.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
}
```

**measureTextHeight() method called in onCreate to get TextView height:**

```
public void measureTextHeight() {
        tvStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvStatus.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                mHeight = tvStatus.getHeight();
                if (mHeight > 0) {
                    tvStatus.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    tvStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the layout params of your TextView as well, not just the translation. Add this and run it in parallel to your translation animation. Make sure you know the text view height before starting the animation (you may need to use a predraw listener if the textview is invisible):

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mTextView.getLayoutParams();
mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mTextView.getHeight());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        layoutParams.height = val;
        mTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

Edit:

to measure the text view's height, make it visible in your layout, then add an onPreDrawListener where you inflate your layout:

```
private void measureTextHeight() {
    mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            mTextViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight();
            if (mTextViewHeight > 0) {
                mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                mTextView.setTranslationY(-mTextViewHeight);
                mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Now you have the height of the text view, so you show it using the function above. To hide it, you do this:

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mTextView.getLayoutParams();
mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mTextView.getHeight());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        layoutParams.height = mTextViewHeight - val;
        mTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

Remember that this needs to run in parallel to your translation animation, so you could use an animator set to run them together.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, I will check it immediately :) What is the value `val` ? (layoutParams.height = val)

Comment: I adjusted my solution to your suggestions and the sliding down animation is working, but not the sliding up if the view is invisible before. How does this work with the predraw listener? I've tried use a `globalListener` like in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16189525/4779830)  to measure the height and make the view invisible again, but the `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` was only called sometimes, not everytime.

Comment: Updated with mode details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm afraid I'm still doing something wrong, the height always stays 0 :( I'm calling your method in onCreate after binding the views with Butterknife(before it is not possible), still it always return 0. :(   `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        measureTextHeight();`

Comment: Make sure the textview's visibility is VISIBLE in the layout, or call mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) before adding the predraw listener.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! :)